# Java Mulithreaded Server Client

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, client

I have a question, I'm currently working on a little project of mine and stumbled upon a dead end. I have a Java Server :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer
{
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3443);
Socket clientSocket =null;
ClientHandler ch;
while(true)
{
  try{
  clientSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
  System.out.println("Client connected on port :"+clientSocket.getPort());
  ch = new ClientHandler (clientSocket);
  Thread t = new Thread(ch);
  t.start();
  }catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("SERVER CRASH");
}
}
}
}
```

Then the client connects through the port 3443, a new thread is created with ClientHandler. Now is the problem, in the client side the socket used to connect is still on port 3443, but on the server side the thread is on an arbitrary port, let's say 5433, so the server can communicate with the thread but not the client, because it has no knowledge of what port the thread is using... I'm a bit confused with all this, does the client class is only needed to make the initial connection, then all the communication is done through the ClientHandler class, if so should i also instantiate an object of ClientHandler in the client class?

Here's my client class :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient
{ 

 static Socket clientSocket = null;

 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {
  BufferedReader k = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  BufferedReader ine = null;
  DataOutputStream oute = null;
try{
  clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3443);
  oute = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  ine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  System.out.println("Unknown host");
  System.exit(1);
} catch  (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("No I/O");
  System.exit(1);
}



try{
  //send
  oute.writeBytes(k.readLine());
  //recieve
  String line = ine.readLine();
  System.out.println("Text received: " + line);

} catch (IOException e){
  System.out.println("Read failed");
  System.exit(1);
}

}
}
```

The problem is the socket created in client is still connected to Port 3443, and the server is listening to this port, so I won't recieve anything from the server (infinite loop). The clientHandler is on another port. Am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re calling `accept()` twice. Call it only once and store the resulting `Socket` in a variable that you can then hand in to `new ClientHandler()`.

Oh, also, the `Socket` knows both sides of the communication so it won’t be confused by whatever port the client uses.

Comment: so the communication should be only made in the clientHandler right?

Comment: Yes; the thread that calls `ServerSocket.accept()` should give away incoming connections as fast as possible because additional clients can not connect until `accept()` is called again.